# Java | Compare four HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap, compare, size

I wanted to ask you, how to compare four HashMaps sizes in java.
How can I find out, if there are >= 2 keys in all of the HashMaps, if they are in the same one...
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example and the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing in the language ...have to write a custom method for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the intersection of the keys of your hashmaps :

```
Set<String> commonKeys = new HashSet<>(hashMap1.keySet());
commonKeys.retainAll(hashMap2.keySet());
commonKeys.retainAll(hashMap3.keySet());
commonKeys.retainAll(hashMap4.keySet());
commonKeys.size();
```

You should adapt the type parameter of your `commonKeys` `Set` to the type of your `HashMap`s' keys : when handling `HashMap<Integer, Whatever>`, you would need a `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: That won't compile. And if it did, it would *destroy* `hashMap1`.

Comment: @Andreas Indeed, `retainAll` returns a boolean and can't be chained. Fixed. Edit : also right about the `Set` backing up the `Map`, which I also fixed by using `addAll` instead of working on the first map's keySet

Comment: Instead of `addAll()`, just give it in the constructor of `HashSet`.

Comment: I would suggest your example shows type parameter `String`, and then you say that OP should change that as needed, rather than showing bad *raw* types in the example. If OP copies you example without changing, it'd work but is bad. If example has wrong type parameter, simply copying will force OP to change the type, ensuring that code is good.